# 12v 8 pin EPS to 12v 8 Pin PCIe

Tags: power-supply, pci-express

I have a power supply that I have harvested from an old cryptocurrency mining rig that I'd like to use on a new rig however the PSU only has 8 pin EPS plugs.

There are six 8-pin EPS plugs plus a 20/24 pin motherboard connector.

1. What would be the best option to convert these to 8pin PCIe for use with graphics cards (for a mining rig I'm looking to build)?
2. Could fabricating a breakout board (eg through OSH park) be a good solution as I can not seem to find any converter cables from 8pin EPS to 8pin PCIe?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Crimp on new connectors.

Comment: care to expand on that? Is it a straight polarity swap?

Comment: Chop the ends off, buy new 8pin connector, buy crimp pins, crimp on in correct order. Not sure it can elaborate more than that.

Comment: Is it a straight polarity swap?

Comment: Both are 12V. There is no "polarity swap", you just have to put the right wires in the right place.

Comment: Or just [buy an adapter](http://www.thermaltake.com/Power_Supply/Accessories_/PSU_Cable/C_00002413/CPU_8Pin_to_Dual_PCI_E_6_2Pin_Splitter_Cable/design.htm).

Comment: The pin layout for 8 pin PCIe is not all +ve and -ve as is with EPS, though polarity is switched on EPS compared to PCIe. Are you certain what you are advising me to do is the correct way to go about this?

Comment: Do you have ANY link to an adapter? I have looked high and low but can not find one.

Comment: See my last comment. I *gave* you a link to an adapter!

Comment: You literally **just** have to stick the wires in the right place. There is nothing more to it. You put the 12V wires where the 12V pin are on the PCIe connector and the GND wires where the GND wires are. Why is that so confusing?

Comment: The link to the cable is what may work for me (though it seems to have been discontinued). As for **'just sticking wire in the right place'**, you clearly have no idea what you are giving advice about as I pointed out earlier the two are wired differently and the 8 pin PCIe is **NOT** all +ve and -ve as the EPS is, let alone that was the gist of my question. But never mind.

Comment: What Tom says is this: Since the signals are the same (12V and GND) you can extract the pins from the connector and rearrange them to suit the PCIe standard. However, the shrouds are not compatible.

Comment: I know exactly what I am giving advice about. You buy the right connector shell (Molex make them) for the PCIe 8pin connector. You remove the wrong shell (EPS connector). You crimp in the new metal contacts for the right shell, and then you plug the wires into the correct place in the new shell. The EPS is ****entirely**** 12V and GND cables. The PCIe 8pin connector has 12V pins (x3) and GND pins (x5) [the sense pins connect to GND if unused] - that makes it ****entirely**** 12V and GND pins. Stick the cables in the right place in the new connector. There is literally nothing complicated here.

Comment: You are either big headed or bad at answering simple questions. You could just as well given an answer of "do it properly" rather than your stupidity in asking me what was complicated as a response to my question. Honestly, this is a question and answer site what the heck are you doing here if you can not answer a question properly?

Comment: @Nepaluz If you look at Tom's comment from the 11th, where it says "buy an adapter" is a hyperlink to an example of such an adapter.

Answer (score 6):

The EPS plug is an 8pin connector which has 12V cables and GND cables.

The PCIe plug is an 8pin connector which has 12V cables and GND cables. It also has two sense pins which as per the spec can be connected to GND if unused.

The connectors are wired as follows:
[image: Connector Comparison]

So:

1. Chop off the EPS connector shells and throw them in the bin.
2. Then you buy new connector shells for the PCIe 6/8 connector (you could buy just the 6-pin connectors and get a 6-pin to 8-pin adapter cable, but no point if you are going to the trouble of recrimping).
3. Crimp on new contacts to the cables from which you removed the EPS connector
4. Plug in the new contacts in the corresponding locations on the PCIe connector shell.
5. That is all. No electronics need. You literally just need to make sure the 12V cables go to the places marked +12V and the GND cables go to the places marked GND.

---

Alternatively, [buy an adapter](http://www.thermaltake.com/Power_Supply/Accessories_/PSU_Cable/C_00002413/CPU_8Pin_to_Dual_PCI_E_6_2Pin_Splitter_Cable/design.htm).

Comment: Forget it! I am aware of the wiring and made it clear in my initial response to your shallow answer. If you can not even point out the elephant in the room that the polarity is switched, why bother respond?

Comment: @Nepaluz Yes, the wires are in different places, I think I've made that abundantly clear! But it isn't a polarity reversal, the ground is still the ground, the +12V is still the +12V. It's just where they happen to be in the connector that changes.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm for future readers, Tom is correct.  The polarity is not switched.  It's still +12V, the pins are just in a different location.  As an example, I have a modular PSU with multiple 8-pin ports where optional cables can be plugged in for EPS12V, PCIe 8-pin and PCIe 6-pin plugs.  The pinout is the same on the PSU side for all of the 12V cable types.  Just the wiring order at the device end is different.